# Animated Switcher in combination with case conditioned Streambuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Following question:

I managed to get a lot further with my dosage calculator app and the state management procedure and now I'm trying to scale things up visually speaking.

So I wanted to change the built widget based on a dropdown menu which actually worked out fine but I'm trying to implement an AnimatedSwitcher so every time the user changes the dropdown menu, the old widget fades out and the new one in instead of just switching. Searched for solutions, found one but I don't know if I implemented it the right way, since I'm not getting any animation, but no error message neither.

I'm supposing I either used the wrong child or something like a unique key is missing (which I don't know how to implement)

Here are the necessary parts of my code:

DropdownMenu:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
      child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedItem,
          onChanged: (String string) => setState(() {
            streamController.sink.add(string);
            return selectedItem = string;
          }),
          selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return items.map<Widget>((String item) {
              return Text(item,
                //style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              );
            }).toList();
          },
          items: items.map((String item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              child: Text('$item',
                //style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
              value: item,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

StreamBuilder and AnimatedSwitcher:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: streamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
               return AnimatedSwitcher(
                   duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    child: updateBestandteile(snapshot.data),
               );
            },
          ),
```

Example of condition:

```
Padding updateBestandteile(String i) {
    switch (i) {

      case "MMF":
      {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: b,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
              ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Zu verwendende Präparate:',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text('Medetomidin 1mg/ml'),
                      Text('Midazolam 5mg/ml'),
                      Text('Fentanyl 0.5mg/ml'),
                      Text('NaCl 0,9%'),
                    ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Anzumischende Menge:',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text((MedetomidindosierungmgprokgKGW*selectedamount*selectedweight/(1000*Medetomidinmgproml)).toString()+"ml"),
                      Text((MidazolamdosierungmgprokgKGW*selectedamount*selectedweight/(1000*Midazolammgproml)).toString()+"ml"),
                      Text((FentanyldosierungmgprokgKGW*selectedamount*selectedweight/(1000*Fentanylmgproml)).toString()+"ml"),
                      Text((((MedetomidindosierungmgprokgKGW*selectedamount*selectedweight/(1000*Medetomidinmgproml))+(MidazolamdosierungmgprokgKGW*selectedamount*selectedweight/(1000*Midazolammgproml))+(FentanyldosierungmgprokgKGW*selectedamount*selectedweight/(1000*Fentanylmgproml)))*4).toString()+"ml"),
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              ),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      );
      }
      break;
```

Hope you might be able to help as you did last time :) Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that you are not setting a key. If the new child widget is of the same type as the old widget type then AnimatedSwitcher will **NOT** animate between them since as  as far as the framework is concerned, they are the same widget. Set a unique ValueKey on each child child widget that you wish to animate.

Please refer to Flutter Docs for [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) and check out the [AnimatedSwitcher Widget of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g) video by Flutter Team.

> If the "new" child is the same widget type and key as the "old" child,
> but with different parameters, then AnimatedSwitcher will not do a
> transition between them, since as far as the framework is concerned,
> they are the same widget and the existing widget can be updated with
> the new parameters. **To force the transition to occur, set a Key on
> each child widget that you wish to be considered unique (typically a
> ValueKey on the widget data that distinguishes this child from the
> others).**

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution! I just needed to add key:ValueKey(xy) to each option, works just how I wanted :) Have a great day!

Comment: Please accept and like my answer if it helped you solve your issue. Thank you and you too have a great day!!!